# how to split two words into single word in a list in a easy way in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list like this,

```
 my_list = ["one two","three two"]
```

I want to convert it to,

```
 out_list=["one","two","three","two"]
```

I am getting the output by doing,

```
out_list=[item.split() for item in my_list]
out_list=sum(out_list,[])
```

I am looking for the easiest way to do the same in a single line,
but I hope there is a simple way to do this in python, Thanks in advance!

Comment: use the list flattening scheme `[x for y in my_list for x in y]`

Comment: an alternative `list(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split,my_list)))`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I am getting the characters one by one for your solution, my actual list has more items not 2

Comment: Then your actual input and the one you used for the question are two different things, conceptually speaking. Post a more accurate example of your situation.

Comment: no, your `[x for y in my_list for x in y]` is not working for my above question too, please check in notebook

Comment: ok ill delete the question

Comment: @pyd: I'm afraid you cannot since there are accepted & upvoted answers. But don't worry, you're not at fault here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a single list comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = ["one two", "three two"]
>>> [y for x in my_list for y in x.split()]
['one', 'two', 'three', 'two']
```

Answer (score 5):

A fun alternative to the obvious and superior in its generality answer by @Yarmash:

```
my_list = ["one two","three two"]
res = ' '.join(my_list).split()
print(res)  # -> ['one', 'two', 'three', 'two']
```

`' '.join(my_list)` creates a string that looks like this `"one two three two"` which is then `split` using the default delimiter (whitespace).

Comment: smart one, seems simple ;)